# Is it possible to convert a string of integer values to fit into a 3 x 3 array?

Tags: java, string, multidimensional-array, integer

I have a string:

`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

and an empty 3 x 3 array:

```
int[][] grid = new int[3][3];
```

I want the string to be stored in the grid such that:

```
{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}
```

Is there any way of doing this without having to import packages except for java.lang.*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your input is an array like int[9]
You may loop through it:

```
int x = 0, y = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < srcArray.length; i++) {
    if (x > dstArray[y].length) {
        x = 0;
        y++;
    }
    if (y > dstArray.length) {
        break;
    }
    dstArray[y][x] = srcArray[i];
}
```

Given your Input is a String, you can srcString.split(„ „) it and parse each item of the result String[] array by Integer.parseInt() to the Input Array described above